# SKShapeNode Invalid Object error in Playground in Xcode 6.3.2

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

None of the SKShapeNode initializers seem to be working, is there a difference between the SpriteKit version the playground is using vs the one in the project. The same code executes fine in my project but I would like to code faster and not have to build each time so wanted to use the playground.

```
var circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Please give an error description to help us solve your problem.

Comment: Playgrounds are fake. Don't use them except for testing tiny confined snippets (and even then they can give misleading results).